# Extract link from webpage

Tags: python

I am new to python.
I wrote a script to get links from a web page.
It works but I can't handle the output.
I wish the output were like this:

```
link2
link4
```

the problem is that the output is made up of several lists:

```
['link1']
['link2']
['link3']
['link4']
```

So when I edit it the empty lines remain, like this:

```
'     
link2

link4
```

My question is how do I set a variable like x = link2 and y = link4?

I tried to remove blank lines but the output comes out with spaces.
This is the output:

```
Process started (PID=10740) >>>                                       
     'https://buckler.link/ZXX9W'      'https://buckler.link/pHXSC'                             
<<< Process finished (PID=10740). (Exit code 0)
================ READY ================
```

This is the original script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
 
url=("https://ilgeniodellostreaming.tube/guida-sexy-per-brave-ragazze-2020/")
reqs=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')
 
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    link2=str(link.get('href'))
    link3=str(link2).split("\n")
    trova="https://buckler"
    res=[i for i in link3 if trova in i]
    res=str(res).replace("[", "")
    res=str(res).replace("]", "")
    print(res, end=' ')
```

Comment: THE SCRIPT IS WRITTEN IN PYTHON

Comment: Good additional comment </sarcasm>. I am getting a access denied 1002 error on your page though? What I am thinking is the following: `soup.find_all('a')` returns all links. Then you loop over them and get the HREF. Then you want to know if the href address has `https://buckler` in it, if so you want to store it. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes , exactly..

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your for loop. You start off on the right track, with the for loop. Then you get `link2` which is also correct to do (although it is not neccesary to put it into a `str()`). `link3` doesn't make any sense to me. Then it seems you think you have to split the `href` value and check for each part if it contains `trova` and put it in a list (why?).

Then, you convert that list to a string and replace the chars `[` and `]`. This is a big no no in the future!

Some working code that might help you:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

url = "https://ilgeniodellostreaming.tube/guida-sexy-per-brave-ragazze-2020/"

reqs=requests.get(url)

soup=BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, "html.parser")
 
links = [] 

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
       href = link.get('href')
       print(href)
       trova= "https://buckler"
       if trova in href:
              print(href)
              links.append(href)

print(", ".join(links))
```

Let me know if this worked :)

Comment: Glad i could help. Please accept it as the answer to your question so others can more easily find the answer to the same question.